# When Node.js enters into uv_io_poll

Tags: node.js

Recently, I started learning node.js and I want to know, what all cases does `node.js` enter into `uv__io_poll` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**node.js** will enter into the **uv__io_poll** for various reasons:

1. I/o operations such as disk i/o, network i/o
2. Event Handlers such as signal, timers
3. Other Asynchronous operations.